# By resize window my flex items does not go under each other by using flex-wrap

Tags: html, css

I've done few sections before by using flex-wrap and it work perfectly to resize window and my flex item containers go under each other.
Except now with this section it doesn't work.
Is it maybe cause of using image? Or cause i use floating inside flex-item?
If anyone could help me out to understand this better would be awesome.
Thank you!

```css
.container-advice{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 100px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.advice1{
  flex-basis: 33.333333%
}

.advice1 img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

.advice-logo{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.advice1 p{
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  font-size: .8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.advice1 p:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.advice1 p:nth-child(3){
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
        <section class="information-advice">
      <div class="widthcontainer">
        <div class="container-advice">
          <div class="advice1">
            <div class="advice-logo">
              <img src="./images/icon-desktop.png" alt="logo-desktop">
            </div>
            <p>HIGH RESOLUTION</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam beatae accusamus at! Adipisci quod maiores ullam iusto esse voluptatibus voluptate voluptatum cumque delectus quos odio tenetur, fugit ex commodi quae.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="advice1">
            <div class="advice-logo">
              <img src="./images/icon-camera.png" alt="logo-camera">
            </div>
            <p>PHOTOGRAPHY</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, delectus dolores eligendi fuga corrupti totam blanditiis, amet voluptatibus possimus deleniti modi, minima quidem molestiae vitae corporis porro ab? Saepe, molestias.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="advice1">
            <div class="advice-logo">
              <img src="./images/icon-code.png" alt="logo-code">
            </div>
              <p>EASY TO COSTUMIZE</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam odio assumenda expedita molestias ipsum eaque doloribus molestiae. Dicta, dolor iure! Similique dolorum pariatur id unde natus, error consequatur quaerat molestiae.</p>
            </div>

          <div class="advice1">
            <div class="advice-logo">
             <img src="./images/icon-cog.png" alt="logo-cog">
            </div>
            <p>24/7 SUPPORT</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet quod aliquid explicabo ut culpa! Reprehenderit expedita atque nulla consequatur aliquid autem incidunt quos saepe reiciendis. Magni, temporibus. Suscipit, ut numquam.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="advice1">
            <div class="advice-logo">
              <img src="./images/icon-wand.png" alt="logo-wand">
            </div>
            <p>POWERFULL THEME</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci corporis eos numquam rerum nisi nobis sed tenetur fuga reiciendis! Saepe dolorem consequatur porro minus omnis, itaque est beatae tempore?</p>
         </div>

         <div class="advice1">
           <div class="advice-logo">
             <img src="./images/icon-graph.png" alt="logo-graph">
           </div>
           <p>SEO OPTIMIZATION</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident adipisci corporis eos numquam rerum nisi nobis sed tenetur fuga reiciendis! Saepe dolorem consequatur porro minus omnis, itaque est beatae tempore?</p>
         </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: It's because you've got flex-basis as 33%, it tries to make sure your children always fit 3 to a row. If you set a min-width as well you'll see that they wrap.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked well by using @media query. It goes perfect from 3 to 2 by resizing the window. By coding so long after hours always forget the small detail part.